# How to adjust the base for a super-exponential function?

Tags: optimization, geometric-series, stability-theory

I have the following function:

$$
T(i) = (\sum_{k=0}^{i/2} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom k j \mu^j \lambda^k ) C
$$

where $C$ is a constant. This function is diverging for certain values of $\mu$ and $\lambda$ (such as $\mu = \lambda = 0.75$), and converging for certain other values (such as $\mu = \lambda = 0.5$). I can see that by simulating the function for different values of $\mu$ and $\lambda$.

My question is whether and how I could calculate the lowest $\mu$, $\lambda$, or $\mu \times \lambda$ value that would make this function diverging, or the highest $\mu$, $\lambda$, or $\mu \times \lambda$ that would make this function converging.

Thanks so much!

Regards,

Utku

Answer (score 1):

$$T(i)=C\sum_{k=0}^{i/2}\sum_{j=0}^{k} {k \choose j} \mu^{j} \lambda^{k}=C\sum_{k=0}^{i/2} (1+\mu)^k \lambda^{k}=C\frac{\lambda(1+\mu)^{i/2+1}-1}{\lambda(1+\mu)-1}.$$

Does this help you?

Comment: Thanks Zafar. It does help a lot. Could you please tell me how you derive

$$
(1+ \mu)^k 
$$

from 

$$
\sum_{j=0}^k \binom k j \mu^j
$$

Thanks.

Comment: @Utku Sirin This is what the binomial theorem is: $(1+x)*n=\sum_{p=0}^{n} {n \choose p}x^p$. You may see your book of algebra. And after that I have used yhe summation of geometric progression..